# get the customer group in Bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

How can i get the customer group of the currently logged in customer?

Currently I have a customer and there are different customer groups. each customer is assigned to one of those groups.

In the script i could get the last name of the customer by

`var glblAcctLstNme = "%%GLOBAL_CurrentCustomerLastName%%";`

but i am unable to get the customer group that the currently logged in customer is assigned to.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer and i am posting this here so that it will help others too.

You can use the global variable

> %%GLOBAL_CustomerGroupName%%

to get the group name also if you want the group id than

> %%GLOBAL_CustomerGroupId%%

Hope this will help somebody.

Answer (score -1):

Do you know if it is possible to change the %%GLOBAL_HeaderLogo%% based on the %%GLOBAL_CustomerGroupName%% ? I would like to have a custom logo in the header depending on which customer group a user is logged in under.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. You can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question once you have enough reputation.

Comment: Yes, mzmm56 is correct.Please don't ask questions in answer this violates the principle of stackoverflow.Also you can use if condition to check the customer group but %%GLOBAL_HeaderLogo%% variable holds only one header image.so how is it possible to show multiple. You need any other way